# how to find mininimum $f(x)$ using $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$?

Tags: functions, optimization, mean-square-error

I would like to know the $f(x)$ which minimizes the  $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)\,dx$.

Actually, this question start from the MMSE (Minimize Mean square error)

$$E[(X-g(Y))^2]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E[(X-g(Y)|Y=y]^2 f_Y(y)dy $$

here, find the $g(Y)$ minimize the mean squre error.

and we can view as $ f(x) = E[(X-g(Y)|Y=y]^2 $ and $g(x) = f_Y(y)$.

So this questions is that how to find the $f(x)$ minimize the integral fomula.

I have no idea how to do it :)

Thank you for your answer in advance !

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty (X-g(Y))^2 f_y (y)\,dy$? And do you know anything about $X$?

Comment: @CarlHeckman I hope they do not, since if they did they would be confusing random variables such as $(X-g(Y))^2$ with mere real numbers such as $f_Y(y)$.

Comment: The post asserts that, for $Z=X-g(Y)$, $$E(Z^2)=E((E(Z\mid Y))^2).$$ This is not true except if $Z$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, that is, in the present case, if $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable (in which case the question of minimizing $E((X-g(Y))^2)$ is moot).

Comment: @CarlHeckman  I mean $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E[(X-g(Y)|Y=y]^2 f_Y(y)dy$ case and X is the unknown and g(Y) is the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $g$ is not identically $0$, there is no such $f$: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g(x)\; dx$ can be made arbitrarily large and negative.

Comment: if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is positive? I am qurious about that condition !

Comment: If $g \ge 0$ and you require $f \ge 0$, the minimum is $0$, obtained  for $f = 0$.  If $g > 0$ and you require $f > 0$, there is no minimum but you can make the integral arbitrarily close to $0$.